# Problème with *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm currently stuck on a problem with the *ngFor directive of angular.

Let me explain, I have a table nested on several tables, and I would like to display elements of the nested table with the *ngFor directive, but nothing is displayed I have no error but on my browser nothing is 'attach. Can you help me please ?

Click the following link to see what my problem is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r2cdua?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You format does match the `*ngFor` syntax but your new variable `ruchers` in `"let ruchers of rucherruches"` is a list in your example and this doesn't have an item named `nomRuher`.

Your example will work if you write

```js
export class AppComponent {
  rucherruches: any = [
    {
      nomRuher: 'rucher01',
      localisation: 'orleans',
      ruches: [
        {
          nomRuche: 'ruche01',
          reine: 'buckfast'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      nomRuher: 'rucher02',
      localisation: 'paris',
      ruches: [
        {
          nomRuche: 'ruche01',
          reine: 'noir'
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
}
```

Your problem is, that you place the dict inside a list (additional `[]` around the inner dicts).